# Is there any sync services library for iphone

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, photo-gallery

i am developing a mobile client to sync images from iphone photo gallery to amazon s3,so is there any sync services libraries that can help me in this regard..

Also is there any library to access the iphone photo gallery,I just wanted to pick all photos, randomly, from the images stored on the device with no user interaction?

Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access photos in the iPhone you should use the Assets Library (introduced in iOS 4.0). See the [Asset Library Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following library (and their S3 example)

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3

Comment: They doesn't have any api for sync or directly accessing phone gallery